# How get browser session ID in zend framwork 1.12

Tags: php, session, zend-framework

I am creating a shopping cart in zend 1.12. and i am saving shopping cart items in a temp_basket table before payment.

there are two case.

1. add product into basket when user is not login
2. add product into basket when user is login.

if user is login, on the base of user id i can save items into temp_basket, its OK

But in case user is not login or first time is on site and adding item into basket. how i get session id for this user.

OR any other idea.........

---

2nd question is i am using thrird party captcha and i am receiving `$_SESSION[captcha]` directly in controller during check captcha. if i am enable a ZF default SESSION for unique SESSNION ID for above requirement `$_SESSION[captcha]` value not receivng .

any idea about fetch php session and zend session both together

Comment: Simplest solution: save basket into database with unique ID and store this ID into cookie.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use

```
Zend_Session::getId()
```